# Have problems when try to test vue css style

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have problems in my unit test when I try to test method that change css style "display" to "none". Test fails with message:

```
Expected: "display: none"
Received: undefined
```

In my component I have method:

```
closeCookie() {
  document.querySelector(".cookies").style.display = "none";
}

Unit test

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(Content);
});

it('change display for cookies class when click by the closeCookie', () => {
    const stub = jest.fn();
    wrapper.setMethods({ closeCookie: stub });
    wrapper.find(".cross").trigger("click");
    expect(wrapper.find(".cookies").attributes().style).toBe("display: none");
  });
```

What am I expecting?

Expected: "display: none"

What am I receiving?

Received: undefined

Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined.

I'm not sure, but it seems my class haven't css style "display: none".
How can I test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document` is not defined while you use jest and vue-test-utils. I would advice you to add `v-show` parameter to `cookies` block instead and bind it to some `data` boolean key that will be set to `false` by `closeCookie` method.

Comment: oh, thank for the advice!I'll try to use this advice and hope it will help me